# Breaking out of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, warning-messages

I am solving a coupled set of differential equations with `NDSolve` for 6 unknown functions of time. At a certain point in time, the system hits a singular point where the potential governing the dynamics blows up. This is not the problem, on the contrary, this is the expected behavior. At that point in time, Mathematica gives the following error message:

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 2.249649036487617`*^9, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

I read about this error, but for most people it is a problem while in my case it is not. My goal is to let Mathematica stop doing `NDSolve` as soon as the error comes up (can this be done with `WhenEvent`? if so, how?), and also to save the time t in a variable that I can use further in the evaluation cell (so the `2.249649036487617`*^9` in the line I copied). Can anyone help me? I would be very grateful.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you haven't provided some code I can run, I will use the [example of the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/NDSolve/ndsz.html).

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can read in the details section of the documentation of [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html), what you want can probably be implemented using something like the following:

```
Reap@
 NDSolve[{(2 - f[x]) f'[x] == f[x], f[0] == 1, 
   WhenEvent[Abs[f'[x]] > 10^6, Sow[x]; "StopIntegration"]}, f, {x, 0, 5}]
(* {{{f -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.386294}}, <>]}}, {{0.386294}}} *)
```

This gives the solution *and* the time, when the error occured. I hope you can adjust this for your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I was able to solve the problem with it. I didn't provide any code because the potential is an extremely long and complicated function that I generate using many lines of code before using NDSolve.

A remark: to compare what I had before to the method you provided, I ran Timing[NDSolve...] (old method) and Timing[Reap@NDSolve...] (new method), and I found that the new method takes longer (factor ~2). Contrary to what I expected, and also contrary to what you find if you apply this to the documentation example you provided. Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: It is quite possible that `WhenEvent` itself introduces the slowdown. After all, it has to test the condition very often during the calculation.

Comment: I win this time back, however, because using the old method I had to go search for the singular point by examining where the potential evaluated on the solution blew up.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Latrace Usually I ignore such a message when it is due to a known (and expected) singularity.  `NDSolve` stops integration as close to the singularity as it is going to get, anyway.  Normally approaching an infinite singularity, `NDSolve` will reduce the step size again and again, so that it takes some time before it stops. In such a case, if halirutan's `WhenEvent` condition stops earlier, it can be faster, if the slow-down due to checking the condition is negligible.  I have no guess why `WhenEvent` is so much slower in your case.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for your answer. In my case NDSolve does not stop the integration. It just keeps running until the final time I specified in NDSolve, giving irregular nonsense after and at the singularity.